# php securely retrieve session data

Tags: php, session, security

I'm hashing passwords, matching user agents when reading session data, and everything needed to securly log in users. I'm interested in ways to securely retrieve/read session data. For example I'm using a function that gets the user id from a session data array...

In db table:

```
a:6:{s:9:"user_data";s:0:"";s:7:"user_id";s:1:"3";s:9:"firstname";s:4:"Tina";s:8:"lastname";s:3:"Fey";s:8:"username";s:8:"lizlemon";s:6:"status";s:1:"1";}
```

Function (Codeigniter):

```
    function get_user_id()
    {
        if (is_numeric($this->ci->session->userdata('user_id'))) 
        {
            return $this->ci->session->userdata('user_id');
        }
        else
        {
            exit();
        }
    }
```

I'm only checking if the id is numeric. Should we worry about retrieving session data even though it was securely added to the db?

Comment: If you go through the process of an integrity check after you pull it back into memory from the db, I guess re-validate? Doesn't seem necessary, but I'm sure there's some angle someone has or can dream up. If YOU put it there, you should be able to trust it, but was it tampered with in that state?

Comment: Caveat: If you're dealing with a third-party service like a cloud server or something else, where it's out of your hands for a while, you should try to integrity check and re-validate what's necessary to trust.

Comment: @JaredFarrish I didn't try to tamper with it. I'm trying to add as much security as I can to it because all db interactions depend on the user id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should **NEVER** write your own session handler.  Use `sesion_start()` and the `$_SESSION[]` super global.  This also open the door to using the [PHP security session features](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.cookie-secure),  such as cooke_secure, http_only cookies,  and use_only_cookies.

session_start() generates a very secure session id that is a cryptographic nonce.  You can configure PHP to pull this value from `/dev/urandom` which is a very secure entropy pool and probably the best way available for generating a session id.

Comment: Tell that to CodeIgniter devs (cause that's what OP uses...) http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/sessions.html

Comment: Just perhaps worth mentioning (although I completely agree with the answer) that even the php generated session id got compromised while back on facebook, using combination of information gathering and brute force attacks; so I'd say that php sessions are relatively secure (the bug has been fixed by adding more random entropy in later versions)

Comment: @Cyber-Guard Enterprise in my post i'm saying to use /dev/urandom as the source of entropy,  which is a simple modification to your php.ini.

Comment: @poncha  it looks like its an abstraction on top of php's sessions because it has a lot of the same features.  I could be wrong.

Comment: NEVER write his own session handler and instead only use php sessions ? Why is that ? PHP sessions are vulnerable to attacks from many angles - one of the most exploited methods in infecting any webserver is dropping a web shell and taking command of /tmp folder - which is where most servers keep php session files. Even if you change the folder from the default, you can still get similarly compromised if your filesystem is compromised for any reason.

PHP session generation logic did not drop from the heavens randomly on a sunny day. You can create a more secure system by improving on that.

Comment: @unity100 What?  PHP session handler has been peer reviewed and undergone many patches.  Unless you are a fortune 500 company,  you don't have this kind of resources to improve your own session handler.  You can make PHP's session handler more secure by modifying your php.ini.   You can prevent LFI attacks and session disclosure attacks by configuring PHP properly.

Comment: Having to be flexible and needing to do things in a different way is not a monopoly of 'fortune 500' companies, nor the rest of the internet who is not encompassed by a fortune 500 company are those with 'lesser needs' and therefore 'can do with less'. There are many different kinds of businesses, applications populating the internet with many different needs and objectives. The proposition that 'some people may not need something' is a blanket statement which becomes invalid the moment it is issued.

Comment: @unity100 As a pentester, the best exploits i have written are for a piece of code when the programmer thinks he is doing something clever,  when in fact it is incredibly dangerous.

Comment: Tell that to the endless numbers of bots roaming the internet to drop webshells and similar to /tmp folder of webservers and the people who are not able to change where they keep php session files, leave aside keeping them in memory, due to shared host limitations. this is why i told you what i told before - there are endless circumstances on i.t. world. the word 'never' is never correct.

Comment: @unity100 Don't reinvent the wheel.  Build on the secure systems given to you.  Write exploit code.

Comment: Either you havent comprehended what i have just replied to you above, or you are just being fixated and insistent. In either case, i will drop this thread. My final word is - someone who isnt even aware that /tmp directories, places where lamp webservers keep their php session files are one of the top targets for webshells, should not advice others on security and safety of session systems. And in case you are not aware, there are endless numbers of websites still on shared hosts.

Comment: @unity100  i think you have never actually exploited a system in your entire life and you don't understand the threats we all face. Thread dropped.

Comment: Aside from getting a 404 page, it is utterly foolish to claim expertise on a broad field by trying to prove having written a few exploits. I will cut to the chase, and just enlighten you : The most common attack that comes against php web sites on the internet comes from webshells which are dropped by file uploads to /tmp folders, which then try to take command of the /tmp folder. Which can easily compromise dozen hundreds of websites sitting on shared hosts in one shot. And php sessions use /tmp folder by default. Get educated. broaden your horizons. And never say never again.

Comment: @unity100 if you look at my exploits you can see that I do use the /tmp folder in exploitation.  (Look at the phpnuke remote code execution vulnerability)....  And use the god damn session handler built into you platform!  Don't be a fool!

Comment: If you are using the /tmp folder in exploitation, why are you recommending the OP to NEVER use anything outside php's session handler ? So that there will be more webservers/sites to exploit ? Admitting that php sessions are targeted through /tmp exploits and then recommending someone to NEVER use anything other than php sessions which by default use tmp folder, contradict.